# What are the functions in the standard library that can be implemented faster with programming hacks?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, stl

I have recently read [an article](http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/9) about fast sqrt calculation. Therefore, I have decided to ask SO community and its experts to help me find out, which STL algorithms or mathematical calculations can be implemented faster with programming hacks?

It would be great if you can give examples or links.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @John yes I know but I want to narrow topic to STL algorithms and mathematical calculations.

Comment: Since the STL algorithms are written for maximum generality, you can beat most of them by writing custom implementations tailored for your data structures and memory usage patterns.

Comment: Note that that fast sqrt calculation is a less accurate approximation, not a completely general approach (otherwise the C libraries would already be using it!)

Comment: If you accept incorrect answers, `inline float fastsqrt(float f) { return 0.0; }` is probably the fastest. There's of course a continuum in the quality/speed tradeoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several of the algorithms in `<algorithm>` can be optimized for `vector<bool>::[const_]iterator`.  These include:

```
find
count
fill
fill_n
copy
copy_backward
move // C++0x
move_backward  // C++0x
swap_ranges
rotate
equal
```

I've probably missed some.  But all of the above algorithms can be optimized to work on many bits at a time instead of just one bit at a time (as would a naive implementation).

This is an optimization that I suspect is sorely missing from most STL implementations.  It is not missing from this one:

http://libcxx.llvm.org/

Answer (score 10):

System library developers have more concerns than just performance in mind:

- Correctness and standards compliance: Critical!
- General use: No optimisations are introduced, unless they benefit the majority of users.
- Maintainability: Good hand-written assembly code *can* be faster, but you don't see much of it. Why?
- Portability: Decent libraries should be portable to more than just Windows/x86/32bit.

Many optimisation hacks that you see around violate one or more of the requirements above.
In addition, optimisations that will be useless or even break when the next generation CPU comes around the corner are *not* a welcome thing.

If you don't have profiler evidence on it being *really* useful, don't bother optimising the system libraries. If you do, work on your own algorithms and code first, anyway...

EDIT:

I should also mention a couple of other all-encompassing concerns:

- The cost/effort to profit/result ratio: Optimisations are an investment. Some of them are seemingly-impressive bubbles. Others are deeper and more effective in the long run. Their benefits must always be considered in relation to the cost of developing and maintaining them.
- The marketing people: No matter what you think, you'll end up doing whatever they want - or think they want.

Comment: +1:  Shakespeare was wrong.  The *first* thing we do, let's kill all the **sales people**!

Comment: Why would a system library care for portable code? _You_ may care for portability beyond Windows/x86/32bit, but Microsoft's CRT defintely contains code that doesn't care. And that makes sense, it won't be ported to Linux. Same thing with assembly; how often will the requirements for `strlen` change? Assembly is fine for that.

Comment: @MSalters: Even Microsoft's code is portable to some degree. I doubt that Microsoft rewrote everything to produce Windows 64-bit or Windows Mobile/Phone/Whatsitsname. Portability is not only about OS compatibility - it's also about hardware.

Comment: @MSalters: BTW `strlen` is a good candidate for ASM optimisation - many compilers actualy replace it with their own inline version. It's reasonably small and it's used often enough that the optimisation *pays off*. On the other hand, you will rarely see an ASM `printf` (let alone `wprintf`) in modern system libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Probably all of them can be made faster for a specific problem domain.

Now the real question is, which ones should you hack to make faster?  None, until the profiler tells you to.

Comment: +1 for "None, until the profiler tells you to."

Answer (score 2):

This is where you really need to listen to project managers and MBAs. What you're suggesting is re-implementing parts of the STL and or standard C library. There is an associated cost in terms of time to implement and maintenance burden of doing so, so you shouldn't do it unless you really, genuinely need to, as John points out. The rule is simple: is this calculation you're doing slowing you down (a.k.a. you are bound by the CPU)? If not, don't create your own implementation just for the sake of it.

Now, if you're really interested in fast maths, there are a few places you can start. The [gnu multi-precision library](http://www.gmplib.org/) implements many algorithms from [modern computer arithmetic](http://www.loria.fr/~zimmerma/mca/pub226.html) and [semi numerical algorithms](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Art-Computer-Programming-Seminumerical-Algorithms/dp/0201896842) that are all about doing maths on arbitrary precision integers and floats insanely fast. The guys who write it optimise in assembly per build platform - it is about as fast as you can get in single core mode. This is the most general case I can think of for optimised maths i.e. that isn't specific to a certain domain.

Bringing my first paragraph and second in with what thkala has said, consider that GMP/MPIR have optimised assembly versions per cpu architecture and OS they support. Really. It's a big job, but it is what makes those libraries so fast on a specific small subset of problems that are programming.

Sometimes domain specific enhancements can be made. This is about understanding the problem in question. For example, when doing [finite field arithmetic under rijndael's finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic) you can, based on the knowledge that the characteristic polynomial is 2 with 8 terms, assume that your integers are of size `uint8_t` and that addition/subtraction are equivalent to `xor` operations. How does this work? Well basically if you add or subtract two elements of the polynomial, they contain either zero or one. If they're both zero or both one, the result is always zero. If they are different, the result is one. Term by term, that is equivalent to xor across a 8-bit binary string, where each bit represents a term in the polynomial. Multiplication is also relatively efficient. You can bet that rijndael was designed to take advantage of this kind of result.

That's a very specific result. It depends entirely on what you're doing to make things efficient. I can't imagine many STL functions are purely optimised for cpu speed, because amongst other things STL provides: collections via templates, which are about memory, file access which is about storage, exception handling etc. In short, being really fast is a narrow subset of what STL does and what it aims to achieve. Also, you should note that optimisation has different views. For example, if your app is heavy on IO, you are IO bound. Having a massively efficient square root calculation isn't really helpful since "slowness" really means waiting on the disk/OS/your file parsing routine.

In short, you as a developer of an STL library are trying to build an "all round" library for many different use cases.

But, since these things are always interesting, you might well be interested in [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious). I can't remember where I saw that, but I've definitely stolen that link from somebody else on here.

Answer (score 2):

Almost none. The standard library is designed the way it is for a reason.

Taking `sqrt`, which you mention as an example, the standard library version is written to be as fast as possible, without sacrificing numerical accuracy or portability.

The article you mention is really beyond useless. There *are* some good articles floating around the 'net, describing more efficient ways to implement square roots. But this article isn't among them (it doesn't even *measure* whether the described algorithms are faster!) Carmack's trick is *slower* than `std::sqrt` on a modern CPU, *as well as* being less accurate.

It was used in a game something like 12 years ago, when CPUs had very different performance characteristics. It was faster then, but CPU's have changed, and today, it's both slower and less accurate than the CPU's built-in `sqrt` instruction.

You *can* implement a square root function which is faster than `std::sqrt` without losing accuracy, but then you lose portability, as it'll rely on CPU features not present on older CPU's.

Speed, accuracy, portability: choose any two. The standard library tries to balance all three, which means that the speed isn't as good as it could be if you were willing to sacrifice accuracy or portability, and accuracy is good, but not as good as it could be if you were willing to sacrifice speed, and so on.

In general, forget any notion of optimizing the standard library. The question you *should* be asking is whether you can write more *specialized* code.

The standard library has to cover *every* case. If you don't need that, you might be able to speed up the cases that you do need. But then it is no longer a suitable replacement for the standard library.

Now, there are no doubt parts of the standard library that could be optimized. the C++ IOStreams library in particular comes to mind. It is often naively, and very inefficiently, implemented. The C++ committee's technical report on C++ performance has an entire chapter dedicated to exploring how IOStreams *could* be implemented to be faster.

But that's I/O, where performance is often considered to be "unimportant".

For the rest of the standard library, you're unlikely to find much room for optimization.

Comment: What if you can detect what the CPU is at compile time?

Comment: You don't "detect" that, you explicitly tell the compiler which CPU to generate code for. And if you do that, then you might sacrifice portability (if the implementation ends up using instructions not supported on other CPUs) and you might sacrifice speed (because optimizations for one CPU might cause a slowdown on another)

Comment: However, many modern CRT's contain code for multiple CPU's and choose at runtime. They avoid the portability/speed tradeoff, at the expense of a larger binary.

Comment: @MSalters: true. That's an option I didn't mention.